# AngularJS Progress bar with block UI

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar, blockui

How to show Progress Bar and disable all contents of the page until page loads in AngularJs

Comment: Maybe this article can help you http://ankursethi.in/2013/07/loading-spinners-with-angularjs-and-spin-js/